# Visual studio solution adding multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have 31 projects, each is inside a folder and i have an empty visual studio solution, is there a way to add all projects in the folder to my solution without having to add them one by one?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747687/how-to-automatically-add-a-huge-set-of-vcproj-files-to-the-solution)

Comment: This one did it too

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891035/easy-way-to-add-multiple-existing-csproj-to-a-visual-studio-solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you have NuGet installed, you can do this via the Package Manager Console (`Tools :: Library Package Manager :: Package Manager Console`) using the following:

```
$sln = Get-Interface $dte.Solution ([EnvDTE80.Solution2])
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.csproj | %{ $sln.AddFromFile($_.FullName) }
```

Replace `csproj` with `vbproj` if you are using VB.NET.

**Edit** To clarify: as Dave points out, the reason this is possible via a seemingly unrelated tool is that the PMC exposes a Powershell interface with support for the Visual Studio APIs already configured, making it the simplest way to "script" against the IDE.

Comment: You might want to mention why a "package manager" has commands like that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders because NuGet is powershell based

Comment: @user1492051 yes, "PowerShell" was the magic word, but it would still be better for future readers if Richard edited his answer to say so. Then they wouldn't need to read our comments.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 (and 2015 I think) the console can be opened from `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console`